# Pandas - merge cells of rows with same index

Tags: python, pandas, aggregate

I have a df with some rows like:

```
1 | FII  4440 | Faria Lima     | 14° | Cascione, Pulino, Boulos
1 | FII  4440 | Faria Lima     | 15° | Warrant
1 | FII  4440 | Faria Lima     | 16° | Warrant
2 | Malls     | São Paulo      | N   |  None
3 | Malls     | Cidade Jardim  | N   |  None
```

I need the output to be like:

```
1 | FII  4440 | Faria Lima     | 14º, 15º, 16° | Cascione, Pulino, Boulos, Warrant
2 | Malls     | São Paulo      | N             |    None
3 | Malls     | Cidade Jardim  | N             |    None
```

Thats is, for the same index (first column), it should concatenate string without duplicates for the columns. Can anyone help me with this?

Answer (score 0):

You can do this:

```
df1 = df.groupby([0, 1, 2])[4].apply(','.join).reset_index()
df2 = df.groupby([0, 1, 2])[3].apply(','.join).reset_index()
df = df1.merge(df2)
print(df)

   0        1             2                                       4            3
0  1  FII4440     FariaLima  Cascione,Pulino,Boulos,Warrant,Warrant  14°,15°,16°
1  2    Malls      SãoPaulo                                    None            N
2  3    Malls  CidadeJardim                                    None            N
```

Answer (score 0):

I noticed that the grouping criterion can be solely the leftmost column.

Assuming that column names are *C0*, *C1*, ..., try:

```
df.groupby('C0').agg(lambda grp: ', '.join(grp.unique())).reset_index()
```